# Strong Reference in HashMap

Tags: java

I am trying to understand Strong reference and Weak Reference,
With the help of WeakHashMap we can achieve easily but how we can implement that in HashMap?
When i use below code, String s3 is not garbage collecting, why it is?

```
HashMap<String,String> wh=new HashMap<String,String>();
String s1=new String("Google");
String s2=new String("Microsoft");
String s3=new String("Apple");
wh.put(s1, "Search Engine");
wh.put(s2, "OS");
wh.put(s3, "Mac");
System.out.println(wh);
//s3=null;
WeakReference<String> wf=new WeakReference<>(s3);
s3=null;
System.gc();
System.out.println(wh); 



// Output-{Google=Search Engine, Apple=Mac, Microsoft=OS}
```

When I do the same thing with WeakHashMap, it works fine.

```
WeakHashMap<String, String> wh = new WeakHashMap<String, String>();
String s1 = new String("Google");
String s2 = new String("Microsoft");
String s3 = new String("Apple");
wh.put(s1, "Search Engine");
wh.put(s2, "OS");
wh.put(s3, "Mac");
System.out.println(wh);
s3 = null;
System.gc();
System.out.println(wh);
```

Comment: Aside: you (almost) never need to use `new String("some string")`. Just use `"some string"` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that there will still be a `HashMap` key referencing the String that `s3` object used to reference:

```
HashMap<String,String> wh = new HashMap<String,String>();

// s1 and s2 remain the same (omitted for brevity)
String s3 = new String("Apple");

// Here you are adding a Map Entry whose key is referencing `s3` (or more explicitly, the same String `s3` is referencing)
wh.put(s3, "Mac");

// Here you are declaring a `WeakReference` to the same String, but that String is still referenced in a `Map.Entry` key (from above HashMap)
WeakReference<String> wf = new WeakReference<>(s3);

// Nullifying s3 adds nothing as well, as you are only setting the local variable s3 to null (still the same String that s3 used to reference referenced by the Map.Entry key)
s3 = null;

// Calling the Garbage Collector won't collect the String object that s3 used to reference (since there still a hard reference in the Map.Entry referencing it) 
System.gc();

// So you will still get the String content (that 's3' used to reference) when you print `wh` since it still has an entry referencing the same String that have not been garbage collected
System.out.println(wh);
```

*Note that, added to your confused assumptions around the weak reference to s3, there is no guarantees of that the GC will run upon a `System.gc()` [as documented in the JDK API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#gc()):*

> There is no guarantee that this effort will recycle any particular number of unused objects, reclaim any particular amount of space, or complete at any particular time, if at all, before the method returns or ever.